# Htaccess open specific file format

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a specific file with ".test" format. What is the rule for opening a specific file format with a php file. For example, when user entered "http://example.com/hello.test", ".htaccess" file pass this file to "parser.php" file in the server. Like "parser.php?=hello.test"; but through POST method.

Comment: You can have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12010923/2279781

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite HTTP GET request to POST in Apache using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009857/rewrite-http-get-request-to-post-in-apache-using-htaccess)

Comment: I did not mean that in fact!! I want to pass my own files to a php parser.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if you are requesting a rewriteRule like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.test  /parser.php?file=$1.test [L,NC,QSA]
```

The above rule would catch any request for /something.test and rewrite it to be parser.php?file=something.test

To only allow GET (disallowing POST) you could do this:

```
<LimitExcept GET HEAD>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it sends as GET!! I need POST.

Comment: You could change the L in the RewriteRule for a P (which will retain any POST data) -- BUT this assumes you have posted data to begin with... So likely not overly helpful. This also relies on the "proxy_http_module" apache module.

Comment: It returns server error: he server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

Comment: Is that when using P? Did you also configure apache to use the proxy_http_module? (and restart apache after)

Comment: I uncommented "#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so" in "httpd.conf" file and I reset. I got this error: You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to use your own file extension rather than a rewrite rule. So you'll need to add it to the *mime_module* section within your **httpd.conf** or **apache.conf** file:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .test
</IfModule>
```

Or you may also get it by adding the following line to **.htaccess**:

```
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .php .test
```

Comment: Nope!! I want to pass my own files to a php parser file.